# MySQL Update column default on all tables where table name starts with ids_

Tags: php, mysql, bash, laravel-4, schema

We ran a script the other day using laravel 4 schema that added a column (service_id) to all tables where the table name starts with ids_

When we run the script, we made a mistake in not setting a default value for the column that we added.

I believe that there must be someway that either via laravel 4 schema or a bash script that should allow us to rollback and add the default value but I can't seam to figure it out.

Can someone please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? It sounds like you have a script that will get all the tables you updated, so you just need to `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ...  SET DEFAULT...`?

Comment: We ran a script that got us a list of all the tables in the database and then did a foreach loop over them to find the tables that start with ids_, I did have a look at the laravel 4 schema docs to see about updating the tables but it only really tells your about setting the default at point of creation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` CHANGE COLUMN `service_id` `service_id` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'your_default_value';
```

where `VARCHAR(10)` is an example, but must remain the same as you specified before.

Comment: Hi Omer, thanks for that bit, the problem that I am having is that there is 23 servers and on average there is 30-50 tables that need updating on each server so was hoping that the table name could be set by a script to save a very manual process.

Comment: Then you go for a loop in bash for the table names and mysql (-e) from the commandline.